# Fastest way in sage to obtain the generating function

Tags: combinatorics, sagemath

I want to get more generating function for this : 
http://www.findstat.org/StatisticsDatabase/St000683
What is the quickest way to do this in SAGE and obtain $F_n$ for $n \geq 7$ as in the link? (when clicking "
click to show generating function ") Maybe thats also a good opportunity to ask, wheter there exist good introductions to SAGE specialising in algebra and/or combinatorics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is based on a MO question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259038.

That link you provided contains code for $F_n$ in general. As the page describes, the following code computes the number of points below a given Dyck path $D$ such that the diagonal to the north-east hits the path between two down steps, and the diagonal to the north-west hits the path between two up steps:

```
def statistic(D):
    H = D.heights()
    left_bad_points = [(i+1, H[i+1]) for i in range(len(D)-1) if D[i] == D[i+1] == 1]
    right_bad_points = [(i+1, H[i+1]) for i in range(len(D)-1) if D[i] == D[i+1] == 0]
    result = 0
    for i,h in enumerate(D.heights()):
        for j in range(h-2,-1,-2):
            if (any((i-a + j-b) == 0 for (a,b) in left_bad_points) and
                any((i-a - j+b) == 0 for (a,b) in right_bad_points)):
                result += 1
    return result
```

so you can then simply compute the following values as

```
sage: q = var("q")
sage: sum( q^statistic(D) for D in DyckWords(6) )
q^15 + 2*q^10 + 2*q^9 + 2*q^8 + 7*q^7 + 5*q^6 + 6*q^5 + 16*q^4 + 24*q^3 + 22*q^2 + 28*q + 17
sage: sum( q^statistic(D) for D in DyckWords(7) )
q^21 + 2*q^15 + 2*q^14 + 2*q^13 + 2*q^12 + 9*q^11 + 5*q^10 + 8*q^9 + 7*q^8 + 24*q^7 + 37*q^6 + 37*q^5 + 40*q^4 + 80*q^3 + 69*q^2 + 67*q + 37
sage: sum( q^statistic(D) for D in DyckWords(8) )
q^28 + 2*q^21 + 2*q^20 + 2*q^19 + 2*q^18 + 2*q^17 + 11*q^16 + 5*q^15 + 8*q^14 + 9*q^13 + 11*q^12 + 29*q^11 + 48*q^10 + 48*q^9 + 59*q^8 + 70*q^7 + 123*q^6 + 163*q^5 + 171*q^4 + 214*q^3 + 205*q^2 + 164*q + 81
sage: sum( q^statistic(D) for D in DyckWords(9) )
q^36 + 2*q^28 + 2*q^27 + 2*q^26 + 2*q^25 + 2*q^24 + 2*q^23 + 13*q^22 + 5*q^21 + 8*q^20 + 9*q^19 + 13*q^18 + 11*q^17 + 38*q^16 + 55*q^15 + 54*q^14 + 70*q^13 + 91*q^12 + 92*q^11 + 182*q^10 + 197*q^9 + 316*q^8 + 355*q^7 + 421*q^6 + 508*q^5 + 641*q^4 + 632*q^3 + 554*q^2 + 405*q + 179
sage: sum( q^statistic(D) for D in DyckWords(10) )
q^45 + 2*q^36 + 2*q^35 + 2*q^34 + 2*q^33 + 2*q^32 + 2*q^31 + 2*q^30 + 15*q^29 + 5*q^28 + 8*q^27 + 9*q^26 + 13*q^25 + 13*q^24 + 16*q^23 + 41*q^22 + 67*q^21 + 57*q^20 + 70*q^19 + 104*q^18 + 121*q^17 + 119*q^16 + 227*q^15 + 254*q^14 + 333*q^13 + 519*q^12 + 596*q^11 + 704*q^10 + 822*q^9 + 1105*q^8 + 1476*q^7 + 1663*q^6 + 1683*q^5 + 1965*q^4 + 1912*q^3 + 1475*q^2 + 990*q + 399
```

Comment: Code is fairly hard to parse in this form. Might be advisable to explain how it all works, as well.

Comment: Well, I took this code from http://www.findstat.org/St000683 where also a definition is given. I don't know how the code works (though this seems pretty clear from the description in the link), but only provided the answer to the question of how to get further values.

Comment: Copies over the definition of this statistic on Dyck paths and a link to the original MathOverflow question.